# Empty line at the end of code needs removing

Tags: java, string, methods, stringbuilder

I have this method that returns a string where a triangle appears on the left size of the diagram, followed by horizontal lines. I used a stringBuilder for this method. The problem is that there is an extra line at the end. I have absolutely no idea where I should put a conditional to prevent it from doing so. Help would be much appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stac[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YujAv.png)k.imgur.com/WujPw.png)

I have no idea how to fix this. All I want is for that empty line on the end gone.

Comment: Please post code as text and not as an image or a link to an image

Comment: You probably _don't_ have an extra line at the end. Your text editor shows a blank line at the end of the file because the last line of your output ends with a newline character. That is normal and correct.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the loop, `builder.append("\n")` is called. One way or another, after each iteration, a new line is added to you. If at the last iteration you no longer need a string, then you can return `builder` without the last character ("\n").

`return builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 1);`